# Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $K,H\le G$ with finite index. Prove $K\cap H$ has finite index

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $K,H\le G$ with finite index. Prove $K\cap H$ has finite index.

My answer is:

Since $K,H$ has finite index, define $[G:K]=P, [G:H]=T$, the number of the indexes.

Suppose index of $[G:K\cap H]$ is infinite.

Define $M=\max\{P,T\}$, since $[G:K\cap H]$ index is inifnite so we have more than $M$ cosets.

Let's look on $M+1$ different of $|G/K\cap H| M$ since every item in $|G/K\cap H|$ is in $G/K$ and $G/H$, so there is two equal cosets.

It contradicts the inifnity of $[G:K\cap H]$ index.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Are you sure $G$ is supposed to be a finite group?

Comment: Since $G$ is finite and $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, the index must be finite. That's the simplest proof.

Comment: The statement in the title is nonsense as written. $|G/H\cap K|$ is a cardinal, not a subgroup, so you can't talk about it having finite index. You mean to prove that $H\cap K$ has finite index in $G$. Moreover, if $G$ is finite then there is literally absolutely nothing to do. This is a mess

Comment: I am voting to close here as "needs clarity or detail", based on the suspicion that the OP has copied their question incorrectly. It would be nice if they clarified it, i.e. if they responded to Arturo's comment about $G$ being finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your reasoning, you seem to imply that the index $[G: K \cap H ]$ can be at most $M = \max \{ P, T \}$ with $P = [G:K]$ and $T = [G:H]$. This is not true: consider $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with subgroups $K = \{1\} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \{1\}$. Then $T = P = M = 2$, but $H \cap K = \{1\} \times \{1\}$ and therefore $[G : H \cap K] = |G| = 4$.

As a hint on how to fix your proof: try proving that $$[G:H \cap K] \leq [G:K][G:H] = P \cdot T$$ instead.